# My datacard goes online but doesn't gives internet access (Fedora 14)

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, internet-connection, wvdial

I am using MTS datacard. I have usb_modeswitch installed and have configured the wvdial.conf file. When I do `sudo wvdial cdma`, the IPs and DNS addresses are also allocated but I still cant access internet.
The reply to `dmesg | grep -e 'tty' -e 'modem'` is:

```
[0.000000] console [tty0] enabled

[11.098238] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)

[11.098352] option 6-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected

[11.102170] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0

[11.102207] option 6-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected

[11.102334] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1

[11.102364] option 6-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected

[11.102488] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2

[11.102522] option 6-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected

[11.102643] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3

[11.102672] option 6-1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected

[11.102793] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4

[11.103074] option: v0.7.2:USB Driver for GSM modems
```

Can anyone tell me what shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after a lot of googling, I found that the DNS entry that should have been made be the network-manager wasn't made. so, I had to manually do that by editing the /etc/resolv.conf file and restarted the network.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

This solved the problem.